# How can you speed up the Rails Asset Pipeline precompile process?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, asset-pipeline

What are the ways that you can speed up the Rails Asset Pipeline precompile process?

Comment: Yeah it's crazy. Octocore with 3.7GHz and it takes 30m! CKEditor is the worst!

Answer (score 82, accepted):

### 1. Capistrano deployment speedup

#### (1) use capistrano built-in task 'deploy/assets' to deploy.

Capistrano has its own built-in task 'deploy/assets'. It will automatically do task for you.

The difference between your own handcraft task is it only load `assets` group to precompile assets, not whole environment.

`cd /home/apps/APP_NAME/releases/20120708184757 && bundle exec rake RAILS_ENV=production RAILS_GROUPS=assets assets:precompile`

#### (2) skip precompile process when assets aren't changed.

https://gist.github.com/3072362

If

- app/assets
- lib/assets
- vendor/assets
- Gemfile.lock
- confir/routes.rb

are changed, it will recompile assets. Otherwise, it will skip the pecompile process, save a lot of time.

### 2. Use @import carefully.

#### (1) avoid using `@import "compass";` directly.

It will both work when you

`@import "compass";` or `@import "compass/typography/links/link-colors";` in SCSS.

But `@import "compass/typography/links/link-colors";` is 9 times faster than `@import "compass";` when you compile assets.

That is because when `@import "compass";`, it compile whole compass assets. not only just `link-colors` part.

#### (2)  avoid using partials

In SCSS, we like to use `partial` to organize our assets.

But only if you need to share variables, or there are necessary dependencies, otherwise

```
//= require "reset"
//= require "base"
//= require "product"
```

is faster than

```
@import "reset";
@import "base";
@import "product";
```

### 3. don’t require .scss & .coffee for no reason

#### (1) avoid using require_tree

When we use Rails generator to generate controllers. Rails will also generate assets likes this

- product.css.scss
- product.js.coffee

and mount assets in application.js using this techniques:

```
//= require_tree
```

But the empty assets (output nothing) which only contain this lines:

```
# Place all the behaviors and hooks related to the matching controller here.
# All this logic will automatically be available in application.js.
# You can use CoffeeScript in this file: http://jashkenas.github.com/coffee-script/
```

It will cost you about 250ms to compile each of them. If you have 10 empty assets, it will be 2.5 seconds .

Remove them from your project, or mount them individually in application.js like this:

```
//= require prodcuts
//= require users
//= require albums
```

#### (2) Don't use `css.scss` or `js.coffee` if unnecessary.

- Compiled jquery-ui-1.8.16.custom.css (0ms) (pid 19108)
- Compiled jquery.ui.1.8.16.ie.css (0ms) (pid 19108)
- Compiled jquery.js (5ms) (pid 19108)
- Compiled jquery_ujs.js (0ms) (pid 19108)
- Compiled custom.css (14ms) (pid 19108)

`custom.css` is `custom.css.scss`

Compile pure CSS and pure JS is fast ( cost almost 0 ms). But compile .scss and .coffee still cost some time.

### Summarize

1. replace deploy.rb assets task.
2. check logs/production.log

   - find slow assets
   - remove @import "compass"; use alternative solution.
   - use require instead @import; ( use @import when it is really necessary )
   - remove require_tree, mount assets individually
   - remove empty .scss and .coffeescript
   - use .css when assets are pure CSS.

Answer (score 20):

I've just written a gem to solve this problem inside Rails, called [turbo-sprockets-rails3](https://github.com/ndbroadbent/turbo-sprockets-rails3). It speeds up your `assets:precompile` by only recompiling changed files, and only compiling once to generate all assets.

Note that I'm also trying to get this patch merged into Rails 4.0.0, and possibly Rails 3.2.9 (see https://github.com/rails/sprockets-rails/pull/21). But for now, it would be awesome if you could help me test out the [turbo-sprockets-rails3](https://github.com/ndbroadbent/turbo-sprockets-rails3) gem, and let me know if you have any problems.

Comment: @nathan.f77 was it incorporated into rails4? I got an error using it `Errno::ENAMETOOLONG`.

Comment: @brauliobo, Rails 4 has some separate assets improvements, which means you don't need to use this gem any more.

Answer (score 2):

> > (2) avoid using partials
> >
> > In SCSS, we like to use partial to organize our assets

On the latest railsconf there was introduced libsass.

Probably things are gonna change and rewritten in C, scss partials promise to be faster