# Slow assets compilation in development mode

Tags: javascript, ruby-on-rails, ruby, asset-pipeline

I have a large rails app with hundreds of coffee script files.

Sometimes when I make a tiny change in a coffeescript file or I switch the branch the whole assets are being precompiled and I have to wait a long time for load the page:

```
Started GET "/assets/application.js" for 127.0.0.1 at 2013-01-11 19:39:45 +0100
Compiled sprockets/commonjs.js  (0ms)  (pid 18142)
Compiled jquery.js  (2ms)  (pid 18142)
Compiled jquery_ujs.js  (0ms)  (pid 18142)
Compiled underscore.js  (0ms)  (pid 18142)
Compiled backbone.js  (0ms)  (pid 18142)
Compiled backbone_rails_sync.js  (0ms)  (pid 18142)
Compiled handlebars.runtime.js  (0ms)  (pid 18142)
Compiled moment.js  (0ms)  (pid 18142)
...and so on
```

I use the following assets configuration `config/development.rb`:

```
# Do not compress assets
config.assets.compress = false

# Expands the lines which load the assets
config.assets.debug = false
```

When I set `config.assets.debug = false` I have to wait quite long time for load hundreds of js files.
The question is: how to find the golden mean? How to optimize assets configuration in the development mode for the large app?

Comment: Have you looked at this: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11390447/how-can-you-speed-up-the-rails-asset-pipeline-precompile-process and this https://github.com/wavii/rails-dev-tweaks ?

Comment: To be honest I don't trust any 3rd party libraries/workarounds. I'm looking for a clean rails way solution for handle cases like this this one.

Comment: Hundreds of js files x 0ms is still pretty darn quick, or am I missing something?

Comment: Umm Rails is a 3rd party solution :) And adding gems is the rails way as far as I know :)

Comment: @sevenseacat this is only an example, generally compilation for a single file takes around 100ms

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's a sad truth, but you don't. There is not a clean way to solve this.

However, there are some patterns you could follow to minimize your pain which if I understand correctly is having to wait a lot in development to see the changes.

As said these have been seen [here1](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11390447/how-can-you-speed-up-the-rails-asset-pipeline-precompile-process) and [here2](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11390447/how-can-you-speed-up-the-rails-asset-pipeline-precompile-process).

1. Take a look at item 2 from [here1](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11390447/how-can-you-speed-up-the-rails-asset-pipeline-precompile-process).
2. Break your assets in many files. This will imply in fewer lines being processed when changes occur.
3. Prefer css/js, they may not be as cool but require no compilation.
4. Find something interesting to do while assets precompile. It may lower productivity but sure kills the pain.

Answer (score 7):

Take a look at [this middleware](https://github.com/discourse/discourse/blob/master/lib/middleware/turbo_dev.rb) from the Discourse team.  We've had great success with it in our rails 4 app -- took reload times down from a minute to 5 seconds in development.

Comment: Perfect! reduced the time from around 3000ms to 700ms

Answer (score 0):

As others have pointed out, optimizing your assets is the #1 way to increase compilation speed (eliminate unnecessary files and pre-processors, import carefully, and use partials with caution). However, why are you turning `config.assets.debug = false` in development mode anyway? When it's false, sprockets will concatenate all your files together, and this can take quite a while if you have a large number of files.

Instead, turn `config.assets.debug = true`, so assets are compiled and cached on the first request. Sprockets sets a Cache-Control HTTP header to reduce request overhead on subsequent requests. The browser gets a 304 (Not Modified) response. See the Rails [Asset Pipeline](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/asset_pipeline.html) documentation.