# Rails/Compass/Sass Compile Super Slow

Tags: css, ruby-on-rails, compass-sass, compass, susy-compass

I recognize that this issue has been brought up a thousand times, and I feel like I have read most other posts on it but I still can't seem to figure this one out.

I'm just starting with Ruby on Rails and am trying to use Compass/Sass/Suzy in my project. They all work (mostly) but am having some issues with the compass compiler.

First off using `bundle exec compass watch` (with and without `--poll`) does nothing. (this is assuming I understand the point of this command which is that it re compiles on the fly and I don't have to refresh the page to see my changes but I could be wrong)

Secondly when I do refresh the page after a change to my .scss file it takes 30-35 seconds for the compile to finish and reload the page. This is unbearable. I've read that there are some issues with the latest 'compass-rails' but most of the posts that said this were a few years old. Does the latest compass-rails work flawlessly or is there a common issue that causes this?

Since I am just learning I only have a one controller/view/scss file so I'm pretty positive I don't have any dependency loop issues.

Here is how I have the project currently set up. (I think it is setup properly but maybe someone can point out something I've done wrong.)

1. I created a new rails project and generated a 'welcome' controller
2. Modified my application.rb

application.rb

```
require_relative 'boot'

require 'rails/all'
require 'susy'
require 'compass'
require 'breakpoint'
require 'normalize-scss'
# Require the gems listed in Gemfile, including any gems
# you've limited to :test, :development, or :production.
Bundler.require(*Rails.groups)

module PersonalWeb
  class Application < Rails::Application
    # Settings in config/environments/* take precedence over those specified here.
    # Application configuration should go into files in config/initializers
    # -- all .rb files in that directory are automatically loaded.
  end
end
```

3. Modified my Gemfile

Gemfile

```
source 'https://rubygems.org'


# Bundle edge Rails instead: gem 'rails', github: 'rails/rails'
gem 'rails', '~> 5.0.0', '>= 5.0.0.1'
# Use mysql as the database for Active Record
gem 'mysql2', '>= 0.3.18', '< 0.5'
# Use Puma as the app server
gem 'puma', '~> 3.0'
# Use SCSS for stylesheets
gem 'sass-rails', '~> 5.0'
# Use Uglifier as compressor for JavaScript assets
gem 'uglifier', '>= 1.3.0'
# Use CoffeeScript for .coffee assets and views
gem 'coffee-rails', '~> 4.2'
# See https://github.com/rails/execjs#readme for more supported runtimes
# gem 'therubyracer', platforms: :ruby

# Use jquery as the JavaScript library
gem 'jquery-rails'
# Turbolinks makes navigating your web application faster. Read more: https://github.com/turbolinks/turbolinks
gem 'turbolinks', '~> 5'
# Build JSON APIs with ease. Read more: https://github.com/rails/jbuilder
gem 'jbuilder', '~> 2.5'
# Use Redis adapter to run Action Cable in production
# gem 'redis', '~> 3.0'
# Use ActiveModel has_secure_password
# gem 'bcrypt', '~> 3.1.7'
gem 'susy'
gem 'compass-rails'
gem 'breakpoint'
gem 'normalize-scss'
# Use Capistrano for deployment
# gem 'capistrano-rails', group: :development

group :development, :test do
  # Call 'byebug' anywhere in the code to stop execution and get a debugger console
  gem 'byebug', platform: :mri
end

group :development do
  # Access an IRB console on exception pages or by using <%= console %> anywhere in the code.
  gem 'web-console'
end

# Windows does not include zoneinfo files, so bundle the tzinfo-data gem
gem 'tzinfo-data', platforms: [:mingw, :mswin, :x64_mingw, :jruby]
```

4. Run the command `bundle`
5. Renamed application.css to application.css.scss

application.css.scss

```
@import "compass";
@import "breakpoint";
@import "welcome.scss";
```

6. Added some HTML and sass to my welcome.erb and welcome.scss respectively.

As a further note I had that issue where on each compile compass threw a deprecated warning. I followed the advice [here](https://github.com/Compass/compass/issues/2052) which seemed to stop it. Doubt it is involved but to prevent my ignorance getting in the way of a solution I figured I'd mention it.

**EDIT**

I figured I'd throw in my welcome.scss just in case there is something stupid in there I've done.

welcome.scss

```
@import "normalize";
@import "partials/variables";
@import "partials/layout";
@import "partials/mixins";
@import "grids";

header {
  height: 100px;
  background: $blue;
  color: $white;
  margin-bottom: 10px;
  padding: 10px;
}

.wrapper {
  background: $white;
  margin: 0 auto;
  max-width: 900px;
}

nav {
  text-align: center;

  ul, li {
    padding: 0;
  }

  li {
    background: $gray;
  }

  a {
    text-decoration: none;
    color: $white;

    &:hover {
      color: $yellow;
    }
  }
}

.first-row {
  height: 100px;
  margin-bottom: 10px;
  padding: 10px;
}

.first-row .first {
  background: $yellow;
  height: 100%;
}

.first-row .second {
  height: 100%;
}

.first-row .second div {
  background: $orange;
  height: 100%;
}

.pic-gallery {
  div {
    background: $violet;
    height: 100%;
    margin-bottom: 10px;
    padding: 10px;
  }
}

.content-bar {
  div {
    background: $green;
    height: 100%;
    margin-bottom: 10px;
    padding: 10px;
  }
}

footer {
  height: 100px;
  background: $blue;
  color: $white;
  margin-top: 10px;
  padding: 10px;
  clear: both;
}

header {
  @include full;

  .logo {
    @include span(wide 1.75);
    @include border-radius(0px);
  }

  h1 {
    @include span(last 2);
    @include breakpoint((max-width 50em)){
      @include span(last 2);
    }
  }
}

.wrapper {
  @include container;
}
```

**Edit 2**
Thought I should mention I am on Windows 10.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `compass watch` command is used when you are using compass on a bare bones project or some framework without an assets pipeline. It watches the file system for changes and compiles your SASS files to CSS. It can be used with [livereloadx](http://nitoyon.github.io/livereloadx/) but thats not the main purpose.

You don't want to use `compass watch` with Rails. Rails instead has a built-in [assets pipeline](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/asset_pipeline.html) which does the job better.

If you still want to use the other features of compass you should use the [`compass-rails`](https://github.com/Compass/compass-rails) gem.

#### 1. Add the gems to the gemfile

```
gem 'sass-rails'
gem 'compass-rails'
```

Then run `bundle` to install the gems.

#### 2. Setup your `application.scss`

If you have a `application.css` file rename it `application.scss`. Note that is should not be named `.css.scss`. Remove any sprockets directives which are comments that look like:

```
#= require 'foo'
```

Instead use the SASS `@import` directives:

```
@import "compass"
```

Then [follow the steps in the readme](https://github.com/Compass/compass-rails#installing-compass-extensions) to setup the extensions such as susy.

Comment: You don't need to require the gems in `application.rb` thats what the line `Bundler.require(*Rails.groups)` does.

Comment: Also when you import files in SASS don't include the extension. It should be `@import "welcome";` not `welcome.scss`.

Comment: Is the not naming it .css.scss a convention or does it cause problems?

Comment: Sass rails [dropped support for importing `.css.scss` files](https://github.com/rails/sass-rails/issues/290) a long time ago. Its  also superflous and silly since the `.scss` extension tells us that its something that compiles down to CSS anyways.

Comment: Ok, @max, I have tried this twice now. I made a new project, added compass-rails to the gemfile, ran `bundle`. Added gem `susy`. Ran bundle again. Ran `bundle exec compass install susy`. I tried adding `config.compass.require "susy"` but it said unknown variable `config` so I took it out. Added a controller and ran it and still scss changes take 20-30 seconds to compile

Comment: Do you have 'compass watch' running in another window? Also sorry to say but doing rails development on windows generally sucks since almost everything is optimized for unix servers  anyways

Comment: I would use a virtual machine or docker to run linux or bsd and use it to run rails.

Comment: I do not have watch running. Yeah, maybe I'll give that a try.

Answer (score 1):

Try not importing the whole of compass.

Instead import just the module you want, i.e.:

```
@import "compass/typography/links/link-colors"
```

- Taken from [How can you speed up the Rails Asset Pipeline precompile process?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11390447/how-can-you-speed-up-the-rails-asset-pipeline-precompile-process)

Comment: This definitely speeds it up a lot